# Append index of items in one list to another in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list

```
Master =[23,5, 6, 34,11]
List_check = [23, 6, 11]
```

Ideal output would be:

```
Location = [0, 2, 4 ]
```

Values in list_check are always in master. Neglect duplication.

Comment: `[Master.index(x) for x in List_check]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting your desired output for the particular lists you have given is easy with a list comprehension, as you can see from other answers here, BUT, you said you wanted to neglect duplication.  I know of no way to do that with a list comprehension.  For example, using one of the list comprehensions suggested here with a duplicate element in `Master`

```
>>> Master =[23,5, 6, 34, 11, 23]
>>> List_check = [23, 6, 11]
>>> [Master.index(item) for item in Master if item in List_check]
[0, 2, 4, 0]
```

Using another suggestion:

```
>>> Location = [x for x, y in enumerate(Master) if y in List_check]
[0, 2, 4, 5]
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want the result to be the same no matter how many times an element appears in `Master`.  For example,

```
Master =[23,5, 6, 34, 11, 23, 23, 11, 6]
List_check = [23, 6, 11]
```

output

```
Location = [0, 2, 4]
```

I would do it this way:

```
Master =[23, 5, 6, 34, 11, 23, 23, 11, 6]
List_check = [23, 6, 11]

Location = []
for element in List_check:
    if element in Master:
        for k in range(len(Master)):
            if Master[k] == element:
                Location.append(k)
                break
```

with the `Master` and `List_check` I used above, the output is indeed

```
Location = [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This is similar to what i had, except mine didn't work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
Location = [Master.index(item) for item in Master if item in List_check]
```

You can also use the following:

```
Location = [Master.index(x) for x in List_check]
```

But in case the item in `List_check` is **not** in `Master`, you will receive an `IndexError`.

---

```
>>> Master =[23,5, 6, 34,11]
>>> List_check = [23, 6, 11]
>>> [Master.index(item) for item in Master if item in List_check]
[0, 2, 4]
>>> [Master.index(x) for x in List_check]
[0, 2, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
Master = [23, 5, 6, 34, 11] 
List_check = [23, 6, 11]
Location = [x for x, y in enumerate(Master) if y in List_check]
print Location
```

out:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the enumerate idea yet

Comment: In this code 'enumerate' just give you loop over pairs x = index, y = value from list Master.